# Windows C++ -- Using DeviceIoControl to return a product string

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to return the "product string" for a HID using DeviceIoControl in Windows. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++)
{
        wchar_t* productString = new wchar_t[POINTER_DEVICE_PRODUCT_STRING_MAX];
        HANDLE potentialUsbDevice = CreateFile(devInfoDataBuffer[i]->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);
        if (potentialUsbDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            DeviceIoControl(potentialUsbDevice, IOCTL_HID_GET_PRODUCT_STRING, 0, 0, productString, 0, 0, 0);
            wprintf(L"%s", productString);
        }
        delete[] productString;
        CloseHandle(potentialUsbDevice);
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting anything human-readable. Is there something wrong with my function call or is it an issue of formatting?

Thank you for your help and consideration on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the size of the output buffer (in bytes) to `DeviceIoControl`.  You also need to pass `lpBytesReturned` as non-NULL:

```
DWORD bytes_returned;
DeviceIoControl (potentialUsbDevice, IOCTL_HID_GET_PRODUCT_STRING, 0, 0,
    productString, POINTER_DEVICE_PRODUCT_STRING_MAX * sizeof (wchar_t),
    &bytes_returned, 0);
```

Also, check for errors (not shown in my code for brevity) and call `CloseHandle` *inside* your `if` statement.